# Facing issue while trying to record a mobile native application using Loadrunner with VPN

Tags: proxy, performance-testing, vpn, loadrunner

I'm facing an issue while trying to record a mobile native application using Loadrunner (Remote application via Loadrunner proxy).

I am using a client provided laptop / mobile devices for testing.

Initially, I was not able to record the mobile app via LR proxy using the client's laptop, but I was able to do the recording using my personal laptop. After raising tickets and having multiple sessions with the helpdesk team, we figured out that we are able to record the mobile app by disabling the VPN on the client laptop, but fail when the VPN is enabled (as the IP address is being changed to the VPN network).

Disabling the VPN is against the client security policy and I don't even have the admin rights to disable it.

As suggested by the helpdesk team, I have tried installing pulse secure and connecting the mobile device to the VPN (so that the mobile and laptop would be under the same client network), but it failed to record.

Network team wouldn't work on the issue as it is not related to network elements (routers, switches and firewalls, etc.), but to the user end-point.

I am not able to do recording with Jmeter or capture traffic using Fiddler as well with the VPN being connected in the laptop. All of the mentioned tools were able to do the recording from my personal laptop.

We are now stuck without any option to proceed further.

Please comment if anyone has faced the issue or has insights on the next steps that I need to approach this.